# Are dplyr joins between different data sources performed on database side or in local?

Tags: r, dplyr, dbi

I would like to have a list of the queries sent to the database by my R script, but it is a bit unclear to me how/where are performed some operations involving local dataframes & database tables.

As mentionned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489695/how-to-make-a-left-join-copy-true-in-dplyr-without-granting-insert-privile), it seems that when performing an operation between a data frame in local env and a table from a DBI connexion (e.g. a `left_join(... ,copy=TRUE)`), *- copy=TRUE needed because data is coming from different datasources -* the operations are performed on the database side, working with temporary tables.

I tried to verify this using the `show_query()` to see exactly what is sent to the database and what is not.

I cannot give a proper reproductible example as it involves a database connexion, but here is the logic :

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver   = "SQL Server",
                      Server   = "server",
                      Database = "database",
                      UID      = "user",
                      PWD      = "pwd",
                      Port     = port)

db_table <- tbl(con, "tbl_A")

local_df <- read.csv("/.../file.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

q1 <- local_df %>% inner_join(db_table ,by=c('id'='id'),copy=TRUE)
```

Below are the outputs of the `show_query()` statements :

```
> db_table %>% show_query()
<SQL>
SELECT *
FROM "tbl_A"

q1 %>% show_query()

Error in UseMethod("show_query") : 
  no applicable method for 'show_query' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
```

This makes me think that in that sequence, the only operation performed on the database side is `SELECT * FROM "tbl_A"`, and that q1 is performed on the local environment using the local_df and a local copy of the database table.

I tried to have a look at the [dplyr documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/explain.html) but there is no information for when data is coming from multiple sources.

Comment: the doc says "If x and y are not from the same data source, and copy is TRUE, then y will be copied into the same src as x", so according to this, where it will be copied depends of what is `x` in your `inner_join`

Comment: FYI you can create reproducible examples with SQLite by doing `library(RSQLite); con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), ":memory:"); dbWriteTable(con, "tbl1", tbl1)`